# Bash script that runs once a month gets emails from file to get email addresses and sends them messages that use another file as an attachement

Tags: bash, email, cron

If I may ask for some help, because I have no idea how to write this script. The script is supposed to be in one piece and every month check another file that only contains email addresses, use these addresses and send to each of them the message which contains another file as an attachement. 
I know about cron, but the script would have to modify the cron file by itself, it cannot be done be the user. The only code I managed to put together is below, but it is not doing the job at all.

Here is an explanation what I want:
1. once a month the script takes email addresses from file1 (we do not need to worry about this file, it exists and contains email addresses)
2. the script creates email messages to an every email on the list in file1
3. to each of those messages the script attaches another file, file2 (we do not need to worry about file2, it exists) so file2 will be sent as an attachement
4) the script sends out these messages

Currently I managed to write the following code. It sends emails correctly, but the part that is responsible for rescheduling the next occurence returns errors. I presented these errors below.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line           
do  
   printf "Sending attachement " | mail -s 'plik' -a $2 $line              
done <$1
nskip=31 #co ile dni ma się uruchomić
akt_miesiac=`date +"%m"`
nowy_miesiac=`date --date='$nskip days' +"%m"`
if [[ akt_miesiac = nowy_miesiac ]] 
then
((nskip+=7))
fi
date=`date --date='$nskip days' +"9:00AM"` #ustalenie nast daty
at -m $date < $0 #ustalenie nast daty
```

date: wrong date: `$nskip days'
date: wrong date:`$nskip days'
Garbled time

Alternatively I came up with something like this, which also does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line           
do  
   printf "Sending attachement " | mail -s 'plik' -a $2 $line              
done <$1
if (date -d "%d" ==1) & (date "r" =="12:00:00")
then
date=`date --date='1 month'` #ustalenie nast daty
at -m $date < $0 #ustalenie nast daty
fi
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Does the name of the email address file change each time the monthly script has to run? And if it does, how is the name determined? Can you describe this more precisely?

Comment: If you put a shell variable in single quotes, it won't be interpreted by the shell. Try `--date="$nskip days"` instead of `--date='$nskip days'`.

Answer (score 0):

read the email addresses from the file in a loop, save the current target recipient and the file to send as variables (maybe you could read the path of the file-to-send from another file that you can update, if you like), and use mutt ("man mutt") to see the syntax, it's not bad.